# SQL Joining table with Min and Sec Min row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to join  table 1 with table2 twice becuase I need to get the first minimum record and the second minimum. However, I can only think of using a cte to get the second minimum record. Is there a better way to do it?

Here is the table table:

I want to join Member with output table FirstRunID whose Output value is 1  and  second RunID whose Output value is 0

[image]

current code I am using:

```
select memid, a.runid as aRunid,b.runid as bRunid 
into #temp
from FirstTable m inner join
(select min(RunID), MemID [SecondTable] where ouput=1 group by memid)a on m.memid=a.memid
inner join (select RunID, MemID [SecondTable] where ouput=0 )b on m.memid=a.memid and b.runid>a.runid

with cte as
(
select row_number() over(partition by memid, arunid order by brunid ),* from #temp
)

select * from cte where n=1
```

Comment: your desired output makes no sense to me. For `Memid=2`, the first `RunID` with `output=1` **is 1** and not **2**. That's just an example, there are others. Please add a SQL fiddle of your structure and data, and either reexplain properly or fix the desired output.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning. I have fixed the desire output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `outer apply` operator for this:

```
select * from t1
outer apply(select top 1 t2.runid from t2
            where t1.memid = t2.memid  and t2.output = 1 order by t2.runid) as oa1
outer apply(select top 1 t2.runid from t2 
            where t1.memid = t2.memid  and t2.output = 0 order by t2.runid) as oa2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional aggregation.  Based on your results, you don't need the first table:

```
select t2.memid,
       max(case when output = 1 and seqnum = 1 then runid end) as OutputValue1,
       max(case when output = 0 and seqnum = 2 then runid end) as OutputValue2
from (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by memid, output order by runid) a seqnum
      from t2
     ) t2
group by t2.memid;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @FirstTable table
(memid int, name varchar(20))
insert into @firsttable 
values
(1,'John'),
(2,'Victor')

declare @secondtable table
(runid int,memid int,output int)

insert into @secondtable
values
(1,1,0),(1,2,1),(2,1,1),(2,2,1),(3,1,1),(3,2,0),(4,1,0),(4,2,0)

;with cte as 
(
SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by memid order by runid) seq     --sequence 
FROM @SECONDTABLE T
where  t.output = 1
union all
SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by memid order by runid) seq     --sequence
FROM @SECONDTABLE T
where  t.output = 0 and
t.runid > (select min(x.runid) from @secondtable x where x.memid = t.memid and x.output = 1 group by x.memid) --lose any O output record where there is no prior 1 output record
) 
select cte1.memid,cte1.runid,cte2.runid from cte cte1
join cte cte2 on cte2.memid = cte1.memid and cte2.seq = cte1.seq
where   cte1.seq = 1                                                    --remove this test if you want matched pairs
         and cte1.output  = 1 and cte2.output = 0
```